# System.AccessViolationException marshaling between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a third party unmanaged C++ DLL that is being used in a managed C# app. I do not have access to the C++ code.

There are two methods being called. The first is synchronous and works as expected. The second is asynchronous and is causing a `System.AccessViolationException`, which appears to be thrown during execution of the second method and not during the additional asynchronous behavior, but I am not certain.

Unfortunately I cannot share the actual code even for the C# side that I control. The problematic method signature has a single input parameter that is an object with a mix of integer types (int, uint, ushort) and some pointers defined as "char *". The other method that is working has a similar signature, just a slightly different input object to populate.

Both unmanaged methods print the input parameter values to a log file, so I am able to verify that the marshaling is working properly. All input values for both calls appear correct in the log. However, I will note that for the `char *` fields only the pointer itself is logged, not the value it is pointing to. I have verified that the pointer logged by the unmanaged C++ code matches the pointer on the C# side but I have to take it on faith that it is reading the correct number of bytes. The number of bytes in each `char *` field are specified in other input fields, and those also appear correct.

For the method call that is working, the C++ DLL prints additional information after the input parameters indicating that he method completed successfully. I do not know for sure that the second method also has such output, all I know is that the input parameters are the last thing logged before the exception.

The last entries in the stack trace for the `AccessViolationException` are:

```
at System.StubHelpers.ValueClassMarshaler.ClearNative(IntPtr dst, IntPtr pMT)
at MyStuff.MyMethod(String& message) in [path removed]`
```

MyStuff.MyMethod is an obfuscation the actual C# method call that I have control over (hence "path removed"). It looks like the exception may be happening when exiting from the C++ method invocation, not within the C++ method, but I'm not sure.

I have been unable to find any real documentation on the `ClearNative` method. I can take a guess that it has something to do with garbage collection, but I can't be sure. The thought occurred to me that the problem may be related to the fact that the second call that is erroring is asynchronous, but the exception breaks execution at the line where I am calling into the C++ DLL so I am not sure.

At this point I am looking for any information on `ClearNative` that may help me narrow down the nature of the problem or any suggestions on things to try that may provide more information into the problem.